# Converting Infopath 2007 to Infopath 2014

Tags: 2007, 2013, infopath, sharepoint-online, migration

We are migrating from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Online 2013.  We have some InfoPath 2007 forms we would like to migrate.

Any suggested way to approach these? Have not tried but what happens if you open an InfoPath 2007 for in Infoapth 2014?  I would also imagine all the data connections and AD logic will be broken at a minimum.

Easier to just redesign from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to just use a tool like Sharegate to migrate them over http://en.share-gate.com. Otherwise some of them might still work depending on what you are doing with these forms.
How many do you have? You might just want to rebuild them in some cases as you say.